# How can I extract an item from a list with the lowest integer value?

Tags: python-3.x

If I have a list where each element consists of an item of food as well as its calorie count.

```
lst = ['Lettuce, 13', 'Onions, 40', 'Radishes, 271']
```

How can I retrieve and print the list element containing the lowest calorie count?

Comment: If any answer here helped you, kindly accept it by pressing tick on left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the list and split the element with `,` as a delimiter

```
lst = ['Lettuce, 13', 'Onions, 40', 'Radishes, 271']
min_ = float('inf')
min_food = None
for l in lst:
    c = int(l.split(', ')[-1])
    if c < min_:
        min_, min_food = c, l
print(min_food)
```

Output:

```
Lettuce, 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the elements by `", "` delimiter, sort them by the numerical value of the second element (calories) and return the first entry as the minimal

`sorted(lst, key=lambda s: int(s.split(", ")[1]))[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting using a lambda, then retain the first element:

```
newlst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(re.sub(r'^.*?(?=\d)', '', x)))
print(newlst[0])
```

This prints:

```
Lettuce, 13
```

The regex replacement logic used in the call to `re.sub` above removes all content up, but not including, the first digit appearing at the end of each list entry.  Then, we cast that string number to an integer, and order ascending using that value.

Comment: `re.sub` here would be a big overkill, plus you can directly apply `min` than sorting and taking first element.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and probably the fastest way is to:

```
min(lst, key=lambda x: int(x.split(', ')[1]))
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: nope. I'm splitting by `', '`.

Comment: This answer was given by @curlycharcoal two minutes before you posted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: nope. It uses `sorted()`.